# Extract specific words from text value

Tags: postgresql, split

I have a query and a returned value that looks like this:

```
select properties->>'text' as snippet from table where id = 31;

snippet
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
-----------------------------------
 There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable.
(1 row)
```

This returns as I expect based on my query.

Is there a way that I can slice the returned text to only return words from position 5 to position 8 for example? Or alternatively, slice by character position which I will be able to use as a workaround?

I have tried using:

```
select properties->>'text'[0:13] as snippet from table where id = 31;
```

Which I hoped would return:
`There are many`
But it hasn't worked.

Is this possibly to slice a jsonb text field?

Comment: There is nothing special about a "jsonb text field". The result of the `properties->>'text'` simply is a value of type `text` already, and you can use [the known string processing functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-string.html) on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "slice by character position", you can simply use the `substr()` function:

```
select substr(properties->>'text', 1, 15) as snippet 
from the_table 
where id = 31;
```

If you really want "words", you can split the text into an array using e.g. `regexp_split_to_array`. Once you have an array, you can use the slice syntax:

```
select (regexp_split_to_array(properties->>'text','\s+'))[5:8] as snippet 
from the_table 
where id = 31;
```

This returns an array, if you want it as a string, you can use `array_to_string()`

```
select array_to_string((regexp_split_to_array(properties->>'text','\s+'))[5:8],' ') as snippet 
from the_table 
where id = 31;
```

---

If you need that frequently, I would wrap it into a function:

```
create function extract_words(p_input text, p_start int, p_end int)
  returns text
as
$$
  select array_to_string((regexp_split_to_array(p_input,'\s+'))[p_start:p_end],' ');
$$  
language sql
immutable;
```

Then the query is much easier to read:

```
select extract_words(properties->>'text', 5, 8) as snippet 
from the_table 
where id = 31;
```